# How can schizophrenics help computers generate random numbers?

Tags: clinical-study, cognitive-science, neuroscience, mathematics

I just found the study *[Human Psychological Disorder towards Cryptography: True Random Number Generator from EEG of Schizophrenics and Its Application in Block Encryption's Substitution Box](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9239775/)*.

From what I understand, they are processing EEG results from schizophrenic patients to generate random numbers.

Frankly this whole setup looks like the Rube Goldberg-machine of random number generators and I was surprised to find the study wasn't published an April 1st.  EEGs are renowned for containing a lot of random noise that must be filtered out before interpreting results, so it's no surprise that that noise could be used for random number generation, but so could any other source of noise.

I don't see how this could possibly approach the state-of-the-art as it claims.  The state of the art is based on radioactive decay, something scientists has never found a pattern to.

Clearly a lot of effort has gone into the study though, so am I missing something?

Is there any reason at all to think schizophrenics could provide utility in random number generation more so than any other source of randomness?

Comment: This paper seems totally ridiculous. I seriously doubt this study would cut it in a reputable journal. And the Institutional Review Board at my institution would be very unlikely to approve it.

Comment: I can't imagine why they think the EEGs of schizophrenics contain more randomness than anyone else's EEG.  Sounds like something a mathematician might imagine with absolutely no basis for thinking so.

Comment: Unfortunately the academic standards at many institutions, especially in particular countries, encourage publication of stuff like this, as do publishers like Hindawi (see for example https://retractionwatch.com/2023/03/21/nearly-20-hindawi-journals-delisted-from-leading-index-amid-concerns-of-papermill-activity/ ). It's a real problem, but the effort to create junk is often far less than the effort required to identify and remove it. There's also a huge imbalance in motivation - the people publishing are highly motivated, the people who could counter it would rather focus on real stuff.

Comment: (note that this journal happens to be one of the ones delisted, though that list is far from a complete list of problematic Hindawi journals)

Comment: @BryanKrause - Bishop, D. V. M. (2023, February 6). [Red flags for paper mills need to go beyond the level of individual articles: a case study of Hindawi special issues](https://doi.org/10.31234/osf.io/6mbgv). Via [@Edit0r_At_Large on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Edit0r_At_Large/status/1653357019477286914)

Comment: @CareyGregory: Do mathematicians have a bad rap in the medical community?

Comment: No, I just used mathematicians because it's a question mathematicians would ask. So would computer scientists so I could have used them too.

Comment: Ah, that's funny. I'm a programmer and mathematician, so of course I was thinking the opposite: "Surely no mathematician or computer scientist would embarrass themselves by publishing this? Maybe this sounds more plausible to doctors." I guess not